# How do I use Jquery traverse methods on selector with index?

Tags: jquery

I am creating a "Roving Tab Index" for keyboard nav in my website and I am struggling on getting the previous element of the current "label" element.

Example Code:

```
$('section').focus(function(){
  var elements = $(this).find('label');
  var i = 0;
  elements[i].focus();
  ....
});
```

and then I have a keydown e.which switch that modifies the index for different arrow keys etc...

But when the user presses space I cant get the associated input which is the previous element of the input because its an array.

How could i do the equivelent of:

```
elements[5].prev();
```

and get the previous element for the 5th label

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that using bracket notation on a jQuery object returns you the underlying Element object, not a jQuery object.

To do what you require, use `eq()`:

```
$('section').focus(function(){
  var elements = $(this).find('label');
  var i = 0;
  var $el = elements.eq(i).focus();

  // ...

  var prevElement = elements.eq(5).prev();
});
```

You can see more in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/eq

Answer (score 0):

Use `elements.eq(5)` instead of `elements[5]` to retrieve proper jQuery elements instead of raw DOM elements.

[Reference for eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)